# 1.8.9 minecraft craft enchanted books modding

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm trying to make a crafting recipe for an enchanted book that you can apply to a sword with sharpness.  I did .addEnchantment but that enchants it as if its a sword.

```
package com.mcrm.uhccm.handlers;

import com.mcrm.uhccm.init.UHCCItems;
import com.mcrm.uhccm.items.EnchantmentBooks;

import net.minecraft.enchantment.Enchantment;
import net.minecraft.init.Items;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;

public class RecipeHandler {

    static ItemStack vorpal_sword = new ItemStack(UHCCItems.vorpal_sword);

    public static void registerCraftingRecipes() {

        ItemStack sharp1 = new ItemStack(Items.enchanted_book);

        sharp1.addEnchantment(Enchantment.sharpness, 1);

        vorpal_sword.addEnchantment(Enchantment.smite, 2);
        vorpal_sword.addEnchantment(Enchantment.baneOfArthropods, 2);

        GameRegistry.addRecipe(sharp1, new Object[] {"F  ", " PP", " PI", 'F',Items.flint,'P',Items.paper,'I',Items.iron_sword});
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(vorpal_sword, new Object[] { " B ", " I ", " R ", 'B',Items.bone,'I',Items.iron_sword,'R',Items.rotten_flesh});
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(UHCCItems.golden_head), new Object[] { "GGG", "GHG", "GGG", 'G',Items.gold_ingot,'H',Items.skull});
    }

    public static void registerFurnaceRecipes() {

    }
}
```

This is the code I'm working with.

Comment: Format the code lines as code, please. It helps us answer your question. Only very few people bother to read a text wall without formatting.

Comment: EliteRaceElephant, I have presented the entire class, including the attempt to make a recipe for a sharpness book.  When I do it this way, It applies the enchantment to the nbt spot for ench:[{id: enchantment, lvl: x}] where for enchant books it should be in the nbt spot for StoredEnchantments:[{id: enchantment, lvl:x}].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo, I found the code for this, and it works.  This is here for anyone who comes along it later.

ItemStack book = Items.enchanted_book.getEnchantedItemStack(new EnchantmentData(enchant, level));

Comment: If my answer helped you arrive at this solution, it is appropriate to accept the answer (and +1 it, if your rep is high enough).

Answer (score 0):

`EnchantedBook.addEnchantment(ItemStack, EnchantmentData)`

You'll have to find the right class name for 1.8 (`ItemEnchantedBook`?) as well as check the method signature, but the method is static on that class and takes in an item stack (your `vorpal_sword` variable) and the details of the enchantment to add (I pulled that signature from 1.14.4, as I don't have a dev environment set up for 1.8.9 as its so old).

Shouldn't be too difficult, the class is pretty small and shouldn't have changed much between versions.

Comment: I found the EnchantmentData class but not sure how to use it.  Could you help me on that?

Comment: I'm not sure what your trouble is. It has a public constructor that takes in two parameters, an Enchantment and an Int (the level of said enchantment).